# How to hide file extension in Fine Uploader?

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

I'm using fine uploader. Somehow i want to hide file extension in front. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxjF7.png

Answer (score 1):

Simply change the file name using Fine Uploader's [`setName` API method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#setName). You can do this in an [onSubmit callback](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#submit), like so:

```
callbacks: {
   onSubmit: function(id, name) {
      var extension = qq.getExtension(name);
      var nameSansExtension = 
         name.replace(new RegExp('.' + extension + '$'), '');

      this.setName(id, nameSansExtension);
   }
}
```

And now Fine Uploader will address the file without the original extension. If you are using the default upload behavior (multipart encoded uploads), then the original file name will be available to your server, which is likely what you want. The name assigned by Fine Uploader will be passed to your server in a "qqfilename" request parameter.